# Do Search Engines Crawlers Read CSS?

Tags: seo, css

Making something **bold** makes it more important for search engine ranking and even improves readability for humans.

To get the search engine ranking benefit, do we need to use `<b>` or `<strong>` tag or are CCS rules to do this recognized?

**In other words, do search engine crawlers actually read and apply CSS when analyzing content?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generally accepted way to emphasise text is to use the `<strong>` tag. You can then style that using CSS.

Looking through our logs I can see *some* evidence that some spiders fetch CSS files. Specifically,

- Googlebot-Image/1.0
- DoCoMo/2.0 (compatible; Googlebot-Mobile/2.1)
- Googlebot (http://www.google.com/bot.html)

Anecdotally there's evidence that some search engines use this to detect if text is being hidden (and therefore someone is trying to fool a search engine with bogus keywords).

I think your safest bet is to use `<strong>` and don't rely purely on CSS to emphasise important words or phrases.